# Trailing Newlines in excel using MATLAB's writetable()

Tags: excel, matlab

I'm trying to write a MATLAB table containing strings to excel using `writetable()`.  I'd like the text in excel to end in a newline, that is a blank line with nothing written on it.  However, I can't seem to get trailing newlines to write.

```
format_spec = 'r  %6.4f\ng  %6.4f\nb  %6.4f\n';
vals = rand(4,5,3);

temp_str = cellfun(@(x) sprintf(format_spec,x) ,...
    squeeze(mat2cell(permute(vals,[3 1 2]), ...
    [size(vals,3)],[ones(1,size(vals,1))],[ones(1,size(vals,2))])) ,...
    'UniformOutput',false);
temp_table = cell2table( temp_str );

writetable(temp_table,'test_table.xlsx'); %//where's my trailing newline?
xlswrite('test_cell.xlsx',table2cell(temp_table)); %//trailing newline preserved
```

With `xlswrite` the trailing newline is handled correctly, but to get the same functionality as `writetable` I have to add additional code to write the `RowNames` and `VariableNames`, and offset the excel location of the table contents by one row and one column.  I guess I already have work around using `xlswrite`, but my question is if/how this can be done with `writetable`.

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to the Mathworks regarding this issue and was told it is a bug.  For now `xlswrite` must be used to preserve trailing newlines.